# Is there a way to save form data into an ini file locally utilising jscript?

Tags: c#, android, ini, jscript

I have a web app that is running on an android tablet that is acting as a kios  that allows a sales person to record daily activities on their routes.  The Web app requires an Internet connection to transfer the data to a server database.  However, there are instances that the Internet connection is unstable causing data loss in mid transfer.  This is a problem for us.

I would like to know if it is possible to save the data locally into an ini file 5hat could be uploaded at a later time when a stable connection is available.  I am thinking about using JavaScript, but not sure if this is the best solution.

The application is written in .NET Core and works great to save to a SQL server when Internet service is available.

Since the tablets are running Android OS, I am not sure if C# would work to save locally.  But any solution will be satisfactory to save the data to an INI  that I can retrieve at a later time to permanently save to the SQL Server.